# How to display Interger in jTextField?

Tags: java

How can I have an interger display in jTextField? I have made a scoring using if statement, but then the int cannot be display in the jTextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Integer Class for your purpose as it will give you lot more other functionality apart from this. If you are using Integer class, you can use Integer.toString() to easily convert any integer value directly to the string or it may implicitly type convert it to String. Then the statement would look like as

```
      JTextField_variblename.setText() = integer_variablename.toString();
```

For more information on the Integer Class and toString() function, visit [Class Integer- Oracle Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate it with a string by using :

```
int valueToBeSet = 100;
jTextFieldName.setText("" + valueToBeSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JTextField wants a string parameter and not an integer parameter so you must convert your integer to a string. The easiest way to do this is by:

```
int intScore = 1;
String stringScore = "" + intScore;
```

You can now use stringScore in your JTextField.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.valueOf in String class to convert to String type.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i =1;
jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

I hope this may provide answer to your question.Happy coding.